# How does Green's theorem and Stokes' theorem generalize the fundamental theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I've read in few places that Green's theorem
$$
\oint_C L dx + M dy = \iint_{D} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right) dx dy
$$
is a generalization of fundamental theorem of calculus. And same with Stokes' theorem. I assume all these can be described in some differential geometry language which I am not so familiar with. Could someone explain how Green and Stokes theorem are generlisation of the FTC? It would be appreciated! thank you!

Comment: I wrote a nice project on this. Short version: it reduces integrals over a set to one over the boundary.

Comment: In the real line, the interval $[a,b]$ (with left-to-right orientation) has boundary $\{a,b\}$, where $b$ has $+$ orientation and $a$ has $-$ orientation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $D$ be the rectangle $[a,b] \times [0,1]$, say, and suppose that $L(x,y)=0$ identically in $D$, and $M(x,y)=f(x)$ depends only on $x$.

Then the formula
$$
\oint_C L dx + M dy = \iint_{D} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right) dx dy
$$
reduces to
$$f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(x) \, dx \,.$$

Answer (score 3):

I love this question, so I will elaborate on the currently accepted answer by Yuval a bit further to give the deeper connection.

First thing to see the connection is that we have to use the right language for the integral. You may be familiar with seeing integrals of the form
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx\\
$$
or
$$
\int_a^b \int_c^d f(x, y) dxdy
$$
etc. This is fine for an introductory understanding, but it makes the generalisation extremely opaque. Instead, let's use the "correct" language with [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

First, we replace $dxdy$ with a two-form $dx\wedge dy$. Assuming $x$ and $y$ were originally orthogonal axes (if they weren't then you get an extra sine term like you do in the cross product), then $dxdy$ is basically the same as $dx\wedge dy$, but the latter is *oriented*. We have two orientations for this object, encapsulated by the rule
$$dy\wedge dx = - dx\wedge dy$$
Swapping the order of any two adjacent axes reverses the orientation. Graphically, $dx\wedge dy$ corresponds to tracing out a square first in the x-direction, then in the y-direction. This idea is extremely important and is exactly where the minus signs in the equation you quoted come from. Trying to insert the appropriate minus signs without considering orientation is, in my personal experience, as intuitive and memorable as a magic trick.

Now differential forms have a derivative rule called the [exterior derivative.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) It is a simple rule that you are already familiar with if you've ever taken a cross-product before. Let's first define a generalised 2-form in 3D $\omega$ which is given as a linear combination of square sides
$$
\omega = f(x, y, z)dx\wedge dy + g(x, y, z) dy\wedge dz + h(x, y, z) dz\wedge dx
$$
This is the most general thing which represents a hollow, infinitesimal 3D cuboid of some sort (it's not an actual cube unless $f, g$ and $h$ are constant functions). Note that all 6 sides of the "cube" are represented, because $dx\wedge dy$ and $dy\wedge dx$ are not linearly independent, so you can always rearrange this equation to include opposite sides with outwards directed faces. It's an overall 2D object because it's hollow. You can use [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Components_stress_tensor_cartesian.svg/660px-Components_stress_tensor_cartesian.svg.png) as a visual from the wiki page on the [Cauchy Stress Tensor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor)

Now the derivative rule is given by
$$
d\omega = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dx\wedge dy \wedge dz + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dy\wedge dz \wedge dx + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} dz\wedge dx \wedge dy\\
d\omega = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)dx\wedge dy \wedge dz
$$
where the derivative operator acts linearly on each component, and for each $2-$form you are appending a missing dimension, then taking the partial derivative of the accompanying function with respect to that dimension. The minus signs come from swapping around order of wedge products, with two transpositions for the $h$ term. This generalises completely to $k-$forms in $n$ dimensions. The cross-product is a baby version (aka less generalised) of this rule that famously only works in exactly 3 or 7 dimensions (I think it works generally in $(2^n - 1)-$D).

The second part of the story comes from considering boundaries. This is a bit more complex because it involves parameterisation (which isn't *that* clearly represented in the basic Riemann integral imo) and I don't yet have a super condensed & simple explanation that'll fit in a SE response, so I'll just leave a few starting points for further research: [simplices in algebraic topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Algebraic_topology). I recommend [this video and playlist by Michael Penn](https://youtu.be/FbSSVUWDSfM?list=PL22w63XsKjqzQZtDZO_9s2HEMRJnaOTX7) as a good introduction to discussing the boundary. Note that understanding the boundary is important because it is the origin for the alternating rule in the exterior derivataive.

Anyway, all that aside, let's write the generalised Stokes' theorem
$$
\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D}\omega
$$
where $\partial D$ is the boundary of the region $D$. That's it. That's the whole rule. Incredibly compact and simple to remember. If you are in a 1D space and are doing simple integral, then this is exactly the FTC, because if the region is the interval $D = [a, b]$ then its boundary $\partial D = \{a, b\}$ are the isolated end-points. The exterior derivative of the 0-form $f(x)$ is the 1-form $\partial f/\partial x dx$, which recovers FTC exactly. This works equivalently for any line integral in $n-$D. I implore you to use the definitions I've given here to show how your equation (Green's theorem) is just the equation for Stokes' theorem with 2-forms in 2D. This also encapsulates the [Divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and the (non-generalised) [3D Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) and the notion of [exact differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential).

This is how Stokes' theorem generalises the FTC. In words, it says that the integral of a derivative over a region is the same as the integral of the function over the boundary. You can choose which one is easier to calculate based on your problem at hand, and Stokes' theorem is perfectly generalised to handle manifolds where you don't automatically have the luxury of a flat underlying space with zero intrinsic curvature.

Comment: Since you are a devotee of Stokes's Theorem (and it deserves it), please spell it correctly. Stokes is the name of the man. So it's either Stokes' or Stokes's Theorem — not Stoke's.

Comment: Good catch; thanks for the correction. I've edited it accordingly and I won't make that mistake again in future. Perfect timing too because I would've embarrassingly done that exact same thing in my thesis that I'm writing up now.